# Error converting date for Calendar in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I have written code for two checkboxes:

```
string sdate= Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Value);
string edate=Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Value);
```

I am getting the following error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's reasonably clear: the input string wasn't in an appropriate format. I suggest that instead of using `Convert.ToDateTime`, you use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) and specify the format string (or strings) that you expect the user to enter.

Using `TryParseExact` instead of just `ParseExact` means you can detect if the user has entered an incorrect date without an exception being thrown - and you *should* check for that. Basically the return value of `TryParseExact` indicates success or failure, and an `out` parameter is used to capture the parsed date/time on success.

What I hadn't noticed to start with is that you're then trying to assign a `DateTime` value to a string. That's not going to work - but we can't advise you on what you *should* be doing instead without knowing what you want to do with the data. I suspect you want to change `sdate` and `edate` to be `DateTime` variables instead.

Comment: @user582977: It would be much better if you'd show us what you've tried - and also explained more clearly what you're trying to do, what formats you expect the users to type the dates in etc.